# Windows Phone 8.1 metro JS app testing

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, windows

I started work as junior QA and after 2 months of manual testing my boss told me to learn about automation.

The problem is that I should test app which has been written in JavaScript for Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Mobile. I searched for topics on the internet but I didn't found anything interesting.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio you can create a Coded UI Test. [Here is an example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn747198.aspx) from the MSDN.

Alternatively, you can use Selenium and the Windows Phone driver. [Available on CodePlex](https://winphonewebdriver.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

**There's one more new and promising tool — [Winium](https://github.com/2gis/Winium).**

> Few more comments:
>
> - **[Coded UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn747198.aspx)** — official, from Microsoft; languages are Microsoft ones (C#, etc.). 
>    It should be stable, but scalability (parallel run) is a question, also you need some time to get familiar with it.
> - **[Winium](https://github.com/2gis/Winium)** — third-party, promising & actively developed. Right now supports native mobile apps & Silverlight apps, web & hybrid apps are coming. Most popular languages are supported. It's Selenium-based, so with Selenium experience it's easy to start. 
>    Scalability: can be included in SeleniumGrid, "out of box".
> - **[Windows Phone Driver](https://github.com/forcedotcom/windowsphonedriver)** - third-party, only for testing mobile web on Windows Phone. Not actively developed / supported right now. Has some limitations. Also Selenium-based, so supports many languages, scalable & easy-to-start for Selenium-experienced engineers.